# If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{d}$, prove that $\frac{a}{d}=\sqrt{\frac{a^5+b^2c^2+a^3c^2}{b^4c+d^4+b^2cd^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

What I've done so far;
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{d}=k\\
a=bk, b=ck, c=dk\\
a=ck^2, b=dk^2\\
a=dk^3$$

I tried substituting above values in the right hand side of the equation to get $\frac{a}{d}$ but couldn't.

Comment: You did right. Where did you find an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having $a=dk^3,b=dk^2,c=dk$ gives you$$\begin{align}\sqrt{\frac{a^5+b^2c^2+a^3c^2}{b^4c+d^4+b^2cd^2}}&=\sqrt{\frac{d^5k^{15}+d^2k^4\cdot d^2k^2+d^3k^9\cdot d^2k^2}{d^4k^8\cdot dk+d^4+d^2k^4\cdot dk\cdot d^2}}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{dk^{15}+k^6+dk^{11}}{dk^9+1+dk^5}}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{k^6(dk^9+1+dk^5)}{dk^9+1+dk^5}}\\&=\sqrt{k^6}\\&=|k^3|\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm not the poster, but I still find it cheating to move from right to left. What way is there to move from left to right?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've made some silly mistakes in my solution.

Comment: @DavidSebastian. Don't worry too much about silly mistakes. This happens to every one. If I was given a cent for each of my stupid mistakes, I should be a billionaire. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You did fine. Repalicng your values in the term inside the radical, you have 
$$a^5+b^2c^2+a^3c^2=d^5 k^{15}+d^5 k^{11}+d^4 k^6$$ $$b^4c+d^4+b^2cd^2=d^5 k^9+d^5 k^5+d^4$$ thet is to say that the ratio is $k^6$, its square root is $k^3$ which is $\frac ad$.